# How to install WordPress with Composer?

Tags: wp-cli, composer

I want to install WordPress and WP CLI both with Composer.

This is how I install Drupal and Drush (Drupal's CLI tool) with Composer:

```shell
cd WEB_APPLICATION_ROOT
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project WEB_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME
cd WEB_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME
composer require drush/drush
vendor/bin/drush site:install
```

Is there a similar way to install for WordPress?

Comment: there is no canonical install method for WordPress using composer, there are multiple widely used unofficial methods, and there is no official golden path. There's also a fundamental difference between what you're hoping for and how WordPress works, your example creates a project out of Drupal which becomes your codebase, which is not how WordPress installs work. Rather WordPress would be a dependency of your project that you then update on a regular basis, not the starting point

Comment: I once created https://github.com/leymannx/wordpress-project following the Drupal template, to make WordPress follow the same logic. Haven't touched it in over four years, still runs successfully in production. It works with symlinks to overcome the WordPress monorepo.

Comment: Most people probably use [Bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/), but you have to get used to it. There's also https://github.com/wodby/wordpress-composer.

Comment: There's also WPStarter, http://wecodemore.github.io/wpstarter/, by @gmazzap

Answer (score 0):

Using [roots Bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/) for a few years, I gladly recommend it. Core versions are all available and are synced by roots.io technical team.

Using WordPress with composer would allow you to have dependencies (WP core, plugins, themes, and other PHP libs) all managed with composer versions. Bedrock will also ensure that no core file is edited as they are stored as a vendor.

Automatic deployment process are done just like with every other PHP application.

The downside of it, is that you won't benefit automatic updates for your app and you will have to handle them yourself.